# Moving files in batch of 10 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python script which has 2 folders, one is source_folder another is destination_folder, what I want to achieve is from source folder I should be able to move x numbers of files to destination_folder, where X is a variable which fetches data from database , so for example I want x = 10 it should copy only 10 files at a given point of time after x seconds or minutes, I am able to move while but not in batches

here is my code,

```
import os
import shutil
 
source = 'callfiles/processed/'
destination = 'callfiles/created/'
 
# gather all files
allfiles = os.listdir(source)
 
# iterate on all files to move them to destination folder
for f in allfiles:
    src_path = os.path.join(source, f)
    dst_path = os.path.join(destination, f)
    shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)
```

Regards
CJ

Comment: A for-loop should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Got This done via below code

import shutil
import os
import glob
import time

def copy_three_files(source_dir, destination_dir):
    # Get a list of all files in the source directory
    source_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*'))

    # Process files three at a time
    for i in range(0, len(source_files), 30):
        # Get the next three files
        files_to_copy = source_files[i:i+30]

        # Copy each file to the destination directory
        for file_path in files_to_copy:
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            destination_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, file_name)
            time.sleep(0.04)
            shutil.move(file_path, destination_path)

        print(f"Copied {len(files_to_copy)} files: {', '.join(files_to_copy)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace these paths with your desired source and destination directories
    source_directory = "<path to src>"
    destination_directory = "<path to dest>"
    
    copy_three_files(source_directory, destination_directory)
```